# How to implement radiobuttons field on frontend registration form?

Tags: form, frontend, registration

I want to add a question to a frontend registration form.
The radiobuttons are just 'Yes' or 'No'.

I've created a radiobutton field and added that to users > fields.

If I add this option to the form, new registrations are not submitted.
The page reloads and doesn't redirect to the confirmation page.

Any idea what's wrong with my form?

```
<legend>Are you a Beekeeper?</legend>
<input type="hidden" name="fields[areYouBeekeeper]" value="">
{% for option in entry.areYouBeekeeper.options %}
    <input id="isBeekeeper{{ option.label }}" type="radio" name="fields[areYouBeekeeper][]" 
    {%- if account is defined %}value="{{ option.label }}"{% endif -%}>
    <label for="isBeekeeper{{ option.label }}">{{ option.value }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's the complete form template.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ siteUrl }}registration/confirmation">

    {% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <ul class="errors" style="list-style: none;">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li style="color:red;">{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}

    {% from _self import errorList %}

    <label>Username
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="gebruikersnaam" name="username"
        {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.username }}"{% endif -%}>
    </label>
    {% if account is defined %}{{ errorList(account.getErrors('username')) }}{% endif %}

    <label>Email
        <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="somebody@example.com" name="email"
        {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.email }}"{% endif %}>
    </label>
    {% if account is defined %}{{ errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}{% endif %}

    <label>Password
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
    </label>
    {% if account is defined %}{{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}{% endif %}

    <label>First name
        <input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First name" name="firstName"
        {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.firstName }}"{% endif -%}>
    </label>
    {% if account is defined %}{{ errorList(account.getErrors('firstName')) }}{% endif %}

    <label>Last name
        <input id="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="lastName"
        {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.lastName }}"{% endif -%}>
    </label>
    {% if account is defined %}{{ errorList(account.getErrors('lastName')) }}{% endif %}

    <legend>Are you a Beekeeper?</legend>
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[areYouBeekeeper]" value="">
    {% for option in entry.areYouBeekeeper.options %}
        <input id="isBeekeeper{{ option.label }}" type="radio" name="fields[areYouBeekeeper][]" 
        {%- if account is defined %}value="{{ option.label }}"{% endif -%}>
        <label for="isBeekeeper{{ option.label }}">{{ option.value }}</label>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" class="button expanded" value="Registreer">

</form>
```

I think the problem is with the for loop. I'm trying to output the radio options with a for loop on an entry, but it's actually not an entry. No idea why I do get the options anyway.
I've managed to get this working with the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[areYouBeekeeper]" value="">

<label><input type="radio" value="yes" name="fields[areYouBeekeeper]" {%- if account is defined %}value="{{ account.areYouBeekeeper }}"{% endif -%}>Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="no" name="fields[areYouBeekeeper]" {%- if account is defined %}value="{{ account.areYouBeekeeper }}"{% endif -%}>No</label>
```

Comment: It might even be the solution but the if statement inside of your radio button should be in the `<input>` tag outside of your `for loop` and should be be:
`{%- if account is defined %}value="{{ account.areYouBeeKeeper }}"{% endif -%}` Another tip is checking the craft logs. When making front end forms the errors in there are really helpfull and show you what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi Justin, the if statement is on another line, but is already in the input tag.

Answer (score 2):

Because radio inputs are a "single value field", meaning that when the form submits, only one value actually goes through, you don't need the extra `[]` array brackets at the end of each `fields[]` array.  In fact, you don't even need the hidden field above it.  That setup would work for checkboxes, where any number of values could be submitted. A great reference for how to format HTML form fields correctly to submit to Craft can be found on this **[StraightUpCraft](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/craft-cms-field-guide-twig?view=input)** article.

Your code should look like this:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" value="yes" name="fields[areYouBeekeeper]" {%- if account is defined %}value="{{ account.areYouBeekeeper }}"{% endif -%}>Yes
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" value="no" name="fields[areYouBeekeeper]" {%- if account is defined %}value="{{ account.areYouBeekeeper }}"{% endif -%}>No
</label>
```

And the `input` values `yes` and `no` need to be exactly the same (lowercase in this case) as they are in the **Values** column of the respective custom radio field created in the CMS.